# Validate the string length in SWT Text

Tags: java, swt

I have many modules in my project, In every module i have text box.

I want to validate the input(alphabet). For this i have to write a common method.

Need some examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for `SWT.Verify` on the `Text` and then check your condition. If you want to prevent the given input, do `e.doit = false`.

Here is an example that allows at most 10 characters in the `Text`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    text.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            String oldS = text.getText();
            String newS = oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);

            if(newS.length() > 10)
                e.doit = false;
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Just a minor note: if you do not need to prevent the input, then listening to `SWT.Modify` is sufficient. The event is sent after the text was changed.

Comment: Thank you.. its k working good.

Comment: Am trying to display the msg box .if the input is morethan 10 character,then it should show the msg box. 

String oldS = textL.getText();
    String newS = oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);

    if(newS.length() > length)
     e.doit = true;
    MessageBox msg1=new MessageBox(shell,SWT.ICON_WARNING);
    msg1.setMessage("Enter the valid string ");
    msg1.open();

But the above code is displaying the msg box, typing each and every input character. What to change for this?

Comment: @AfshanAhamed From the code you posted it looks like your `if` content isn't contained in curly brackets (`{` and `}`).